# CakePHP relacionamento HABTM

Tags: cakephp, habtm

Estou com uma dúvida relacionada ao **Framework CakePHP**. É o seguinte:

Suponha-se que temos uma relação `hasAndBelongsToMany` (HABTM) entre um Model `Pessoas` e `Projetos`, com tabelas de mesmo nome. A join table é **pessoas_projetos.**

Na tabela `Pessoas`, há a PrimaryKey **id** e o campo **cpf**.

Na view **add.ctp** de `Projetos`, preciso DIGITAR o **cpf** e encontrar a `Pessoa` pelo **id** para realizar a conexão entre eles. Como faço isso?

Comment: O que você tentou até o momento?

Comment: Você vai precisar criar uma action no controller `pessoas` para buscar a pessoa pelo CPF, após isto, vai redirecionar para o controller `projetos` -> action `add` passando o `id` da pessoa como parâmetro.

Basicamente, este é o caminho, há também outras formas, utilizando ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho duas sujestões pra você, veja qual te atende e use-a, claro se der certo.

Suponhamos que seu relacionamento no Model PROJETOS seja assim:

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
     'Pessoas' => array(
         'joinTable' => 'pessoas_projetos',
         'foreignKey' => 'cpf',                         // Sua FK na tabela de relação
         'associationForeignKey' => 'projeto_id',   // Sua FK na tabela de relação
        'conditions' => array(),
     ),
 );
```

E o seu Pessoas seja assim:

```
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
     'Projetos' => array(
         'joinTable' => 'pessoas_projetos',
         'foreignKey' => 'projeto_id',      // Sua FK na tabela de relação
         'associationForeignKey' => 'cpf',  // Sua FK na tabela de relação
        'conditions' => array(),
     ),
 );
```

**Sujestão Simples:**

Desde que seu Model esteja relacionado das duas partes (Tanto de Pessoas para Projetos, quanto de Projetos para Pessoas), é simples, só fazer a query direto no Model Pessoas passando na condição o CPF, mais ou menos assim:

Esse caso é se sua query tiver sendo feita no Model Pessoa

No seu controller

```
$query = array(
    'field' => 'Pessoas.*',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Pessoas.cpf' => $cpf,
    ),
);

$data = $this->Pessoa->find('all', $query);

debug($data);
```

**Sujestão menos simples:**

Caso você esteje fazendo sua query no model de Projeto, você precisa criar um Join na sua query para poder usar essa condição.

No seu controller:

```
$query = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            "table" => "pessoas_projetos",
            "alias" => "PessoasProjetos",
            "type" => "LEFT",
            "conditions" => array(
                "Projetos.id = PessoasProjetos.projeto_id"
            )
        ),
    ),
    'field' => '...',
    'conditions' => array(
        'PessoasProjetos.cpf' => $cpf
    ),
);

$data = $this->Projeto->find('all', $query);

debug($data);
```

No Joins é que é aplicado o relacionamento quando você precisa usar condições nas tabelas de ligação N:N

Lembrando que essas condições são validas, somente se os Models estiverem relacionados corretamente.

Comment: Então como ficaria o `add.tcp` para adicionar projetos buscando pessoas e salvar na tabela pessoas_projetos???